# Group homomorphism between $S_n$ and $\mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, quotient-spaces

So the question is:

> What are the group homomorphism between $S_n$ and $\mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z}$

Now my instinct would be to consider a homomorphism $f$ between $S_n$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $\text{K} (f) = \mathbb{3Z}$, then I would be able to state that the exists a unique bijective $f'$ homomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, and then I would need to construct the reciprocal function(which does exist as $f'$ is bijective). Now the issue is that I don't know what kind of $f$ I can construct. Can you help me on this?

And furthermore, is there any other way to proceed to get a different group homomorphism?

Comment: Note you are not asked to provide bijective (or, even weaker, either injective or surjective map) - i.e. the problem is not about finding isomorphisms (or, weaker, monomorphisms or epimorphisms), if I remember the terminology correctly... The problem is just to find a homomorphism.

Comment: @user8734617 Indeed I agree with you, I started with the bijective one because it was the first one to come to my mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The group $S_n $ is generated by the transpositions $\sigma_{i,j}$, which are permutations that just swap two elements $i $ and $j $, leaving everything else unchanged. Any homomorphism $f $ of $S_n $ into $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z $ must map those transpositions into identity, because they are of order 2, and the only element in $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z $ that, squared, gives the identity is the identity itself. Therefore, as all the generators of $S_n $ must be mapped to identity, the homomorphism must map all the other elements to identity. Thus, every homomorphism of $S_n $ into $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z $ is trivial.

Comment: I understand your reasoning. So the only possible homomoprhisme would be $\forall \sigma \in S_n, f(\sigma) = \bar{1}$, where $\bar{1}$ is the class of $1$?

Comment: Really the class of $0$, which is the neutral in $\mathbb Z $ - but yes, your understanding is right.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* If $f: S_n \to \mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z}$ is a homomorphism, then $\ker f$ is a normal subgroup of $S_n$. The normal subgroups of $S_n$ are well known. Moreover, the image of $f$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z}$ and so is either trivial or the whole group. Does $S_n$ have a normal subgroups of index $3$?

Comment: The normal subgroups of $S_n$ are $\{id , A_n, S_n \}$, if I construct a $f$ homomorphism such that $f(\sigma)$ equals the number of transpositions it is made of, then $A_n$ would be the $Ker(f)$. Right?

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is a homomorphism from $S_n$ to $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, the image is abelian. Hence the commutator subgroup $[S_n,S_n]=A_n \subseteq ker(f)$. But $|S_n:A_n|=2$, so $|S_n:ker(f)|$ must divide $2$ ... can you finish?

Comment: I don't really follow your line of thought. I guess $|S_n: ker(f)|$ is either equal to $1$ or to $2$. But I don't see the link with $\mathbb{Z}/ 3\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Ok, $f(S_n)$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, hence $f$ is either trivial (sending everything to the identity) or it is surjective. In the latter case $S_n/ker(f) \cong \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$, that is, $|S_n:ker(f)|=3$, which is absurd given my prior remark. So you can solve this hands-down, without any considerations about cycles. In a similar vein: every homomorphism from $S_n$ to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is trivial, when $p$ is an odd prime.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $\ker \phi \unlhd S_n$.  Let $\phi$ be the non-trivial homomorphism. Then we have by First Isomorphism Theorem that $S_n/\ker \phi \cong \phi[S_n] \cong \mathbb{Z_3}$. Now how many normal subgroup od index $3$ does $S_n$ have?

Comment: I don't see how I can conclude the number the number of normal subgroups of index $3$ that $S_n$ has.

Comment: @JohnMayne It has none. As for $n\ge 5$ only the alternating group is the normal group of $S_n$. The other cases can be easily discarded separately